# Trouble solving polynomial equation with exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, exponentiation, exponential-function

I'm having trouble solving this equation.It looks simple, but I just can't find the answer.Can someone help me?

$$9x^4-13x^2+4 = 0$$

Comment: Hint: let $z=x^2$, solve for $z$. Now solve for $x$.

Comment: @elisa: Another observation, other than David's excellent hint, look at the numbers, you see $9, -13, 4$, so what is $x$ in that case? Now, this reduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t = x^2$ then we have $9t^2 - 13t + 4=0$

This factorises to give $(9t-4)(t-1)=0$ so our solutions are $t = \frac{4}{9}$ or $t=1$.

So $x = \pm\frac{2}{3}$ or $x=\pm1$.